# Trying to create a new column using multiple if else statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I would like to create a new column that classifies a person's BMI into certain categories.

I am not sure where I am going wrong:

```
brfss2013 <- brfss2013 %>%
  mutate(bmi_class = if (X_bmi5 < 18.5) {
    X_bmi5 == 'underweight'}
    else if (X_bmi5 in range(18.5,24.9)){
      X_bmi5 =='normal'} 
    else if (X_bmi5 in range(25,29.9)) {
      X_bmi5 =='overweight'}
    else if (X_bmi5 in range(30,34.9)){
      X_bmi5 =='class 1 obesity'}
    else if (X_bmi5 in range(35,39.9)){
      X_bmi5 =='class 2 obesity'
    else if (X_bmi5 > 39.9){
      X_bmi5 == 'class 3 obesity')}
      else 'NA')
```

Comment: I think you'd probably prefer using `cut()`, or possibly `case_when()`. But `cut()` would be my first choice.

Comment: @joran why cut()?

Comment: Because `cut()` is literally designed for this exact task: take a numeric vector and split it into bins based on a set of break points. That's what it is for.

Comment: I guess I should add that each `X_bmi5 in range(18.5,24.9)` isn't valid R syntax. There is an operator `%in%`, but that still won't do what you intend. If you literally wanted to write out each if/else statement (which isn't necessary) you'd have to do something like `X_bmi5 >= 18.5 & X_bmi5 < 24.9`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@joran already mentioned `cut` function. So here is the code:

```
# Fake data
brfss2013 <- data.frame(X_bmi5 = rnorm(30, 28, 5))

labels <- c('underweight', 'normal', 'overweight',
            'class 1 obesity', 'class 2 obesity', 'class 3 obesity')
breaks <- c(0, 18.5, 24.9, 29.9, 34.9, 39.9, 1000)
brfss2013 <- brfss2013 %>%
             mutate(brfss2013 = cut(X_bmi5, breaks = breaks,
                    labels = labels, include.lowest = TRUE))
```