# Multiple if else statements to classify existing values in a new column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I have tried reproducing the method described in this post ([Trying to create a new column using multiple if else statements in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773291/trying-to-create-a-new-column-using-multiple-if-else-statements-in-r))

I would like to classify the severity of a patients blood work. My intention is to give a certain score (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3) to an already existing value for each patient's blood work value. After that, I want to save these new values into a new column.
The cut off values are:

```
if value is >=150000, score = 0
if value is <150000, score = 1
if value is <100000, score = 2
if value is <50000, score = 3
if value is <20000, score = 4
```

dput is

```
> dput (platelets_v1)
structure(list(ID = c(13055908, 13059026, 13154920, 13201107, 
13207119, 13207948, 13234892, 13261022, 13082943, 13193903, 13259391, 
13283776, 13262499, 13154288, 13207315, 13269178, 13135316, 13055690, 
13207670, 13220627, 13233898, 13055009, 13044947, 13181075, 13261607, 
13186960, 13240091, 13060589, 13201616, 13260671, 13302375, 13021555, 
13054278, 13062360, 13035346, 13077712, 13128769, 13267480, 13160156, 
13040172, 13160971, 13239318, 12977871, 13090190, 13321288, 13040530, 
13100979, 13124511, 13192142, 13289317, 13315577, 13154966, 13044653, 
13079694, 13128639, 13165362, 13207352, 13049409, 12999835, 13210994, 
13283675, 13223721, 13064865, 13104602, 13036280, 13040507, 12964437, 
13029805, 13029001, 12993036, 13072516, 13060586, 13119819, 13040632
), platelets = c("469.000", "NA", "NA", "243.000", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "334.000", "522.000", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "312.000", 
"421.000", "NA", "321.000", "NA", "NA", "NA", "298.000", "263.000", 
"109.000", "280.000", "NA", "NA", "430.000", "288.000", "159.000", 
"528.000", "NA", "163.000", "NA", "439.000", "NA", "477.000", 
"NA", "473.000", "NA", "459.000", "183.000", "343.000", "285.000", 
"459.000", "253.000", "NA", "227.000", "NA", "569.000", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "239.000", "382.000", "270.000", "NA", "362.000", 
"NA", "146.000", "367.000", "NA", "531.000", "NA", "363000", 
"NA", "257000", "158000", "56000", "417", "NA", "171000", "NA", 
"NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, -74L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have tried the following:

```
> labels <- c('0', '1', '2','3', '4')
> breaks <- c(500000, 150000, 100000, 50000, 20000)
> teste01 <- platelets_v1 %>% mutate(platelets_v1 = cut(platelets_v1, breaks = breaks, labels = labels, include.lowest = TRUE))
```

Desired result:

```
ID platelets score
13055908 469000 0
13059026 NA NA
13154920 NA NA
13201107 243000 0
```

and so on

Any light would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `case_when` or cut()

Comment: Since the output is numeric, `findInterval` is the best option.

Comment: Platelets in dataframe seems of character type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
platelets_v1 %>%
  mutate(
    platelets = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(platelets)),
    bin = 5L - cut(platelets,
                   c(0, 20000, 50000, 100000, 150000, Inf), labels = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  slice(c(1:5, n() - 0:4))
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#          ID platelets   bin
#       <dbl> <chr>     <int>
#  1 13055908 469.000       4
#  2 13059026 NA           NA
#  3 13154920 NA           NA
#  4 13201107 243.000       4
#  5 13207119 NA           NA
#  6 13040632 NA           NA
#  7 13119819 NA           NA
#  8 13060586 NA           NA
#  9 13072516 171000        0
# 10 12993036 NA           NA
```

or

```r
platelets_v1 %>%
  mutate(
    platelets = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(platelets)),
    bin = 5L - findInterval(platelets,
                            c(0, 20000, 50000, 100000, 150000, Inf))
  )
```

But if you want the generic ability to find ranges that may not be perfectly aligned (left-closed, right-open), then

```r
platelets_v1 %>%
  mutate(
    platelets = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(platelets)),
    bin = case_when(
      platelets < 20000 ~ 4, 
      platelets < 50000 ~ 3, 
      platelets < 100000 ~ 2, 
      platelets < 150000 ~ 1, 
      platelets >= 150000 ~ 0)
    )
```

The order here matters, since if you reversed them, everything would be either `0` or `1` (and `NA`). Also, one might be tempted to use `between` ... realize that this is "closed" on both sides, so `between(platelets, 20000, 50000)` is equivalent to `20000 <= platelets & platelets <= 50000`, where your logic suggests you prefer `... & platelets < 50000`.

Also, one might be tempted to replace `platelets >= 150000 ~ 0` with `TRUE ~ 0` as an assumption that all remaining values must be in that category. Since your data includes `NA`, I recommend against that, preferring to keep the default value of `NA` for unmet conditions.

Comment: This is absolutely on point on what I needed. Thank you so much. I am not replacing ```platelets >= 15000 ~0``` with ```TRUE ~0``` as I need ```NA``` to be disclosed.
I find the ```case_when```  solution very elegant and easy to understand.
One question though is why the order matters, showing 0 and 1? Does it mean anytime I need to classify a set of values I have to begin by the highest interval and highest score (e.g  ```platelets < 20000 ~ 4```)?

Comment: One premise with `case_when` is that the first condition that is true is retained. If you have `< 100000` and then `< 1000`, the second will never be used because every number that is under 1000 is also under 100000 (obviously).

Comment: An easy way to verify that is to reverse the order of the conditions in the `case_when` code block above and rerun ... and see that all of your data will only contain `NA`, `0`, and `1`.

Comment: I have inversed the order of the conditions and it worked just fine for a particular case where I needed to classify another blood work. Thank you so much. If possible, let me know how can I pay you a coffee as a token of appreciation.